# Installing Emscripten on Windows - Python SSL root certificates

Tags: python, emscripten

Running "emsdk install latest" from emcmdprompt.bat gives me the following:

```
Resolving SDK alias 'latest' to '2.0.30'
Resolving SDK version '2.0.30' to 'sdk-releases-upstream-c69458f1bbf3ef5b8da4e934de210659cc9bca04-64bit'
Installing SDK 'sdk-releases-upstream-c69458f1bbf3ef5b8da4e934de210659cc9bca04-64bit'..
Installing tool 'node-14.15.5-64bit'..
Error: Downloading URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/deps/node-v14.15.5-win-x64.zip': <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
Warning: Possibly SSL/TLS issue. Update or install Python SSL root certificates (2048-bit or greater) supplied in Python folder or https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ and try again.
error: installation failed!
```

Running pip install certifi in Anaconda prompt gives me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\...\anaconda\lib\site-packages (2019.6.16)
```

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Edit: For additional background, in case the certifi version matters, I tried updating it in the anaconda prompt and got

```
Collecting certifi
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/1b/0a0dece0e8aa492a6ec9e4ad2fe366b511558cdc73fd3abc82ba7348e875/certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 344kB/s
Installing collected packages: certifi
  Found existing installation: certifi 2019.6.16
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'certifi'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: I now installed certifi using pip install --ignore-installed certifi, but I am getting the same "Possibly SSL/TLS issue" when trying to install emsdk.